Expo app immediately crashing in TestFlight
My Expo app crashes immediately when started in TestFlight. The app is working correctly in --no-dev mode.
Side note: the application had some uncaught exception originating from SplashScreen handling but that seems to have disappeared  by moving SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync(); outside the app entry point class.
I've set the ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler handler to muting all errors.
How can I come to better understanding of where the problem is to be able to fix it?
Crash report:
Incident Identifier: 27B3A01B-8E32-4564-8ABA-4B833E901F4B
Distributor ID:      com.apple.TestFlight
Hardware Model:      iPhone13,2
Process:             XXX [20508]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3CE6E33A-1730-4AF2-B773-744CB3184871/XXX.app/XXX
Identifier:          com.xxx
Version:             1.0.4 (5)
AppStoreTools:       15F31e
AppVariant:          1:iPhone13,2:17.4
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.xxx [2937]

Date/Time:           2024-07-15 01:46:02.3170 +0200
Launch Time:         2024-07-15 01:46:00.5863 +0200
OS Version:          iPhone OS 17.5.1 (21F90)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    4.50.06
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process: XXX [20508]

Triggered by Thread:  19

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1a25ecf20 __exceptionPreprocess + 164 (NSException.m:249)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x19a49a018 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:356)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1a26eb580 -[NSException raise] + 16 (NSException.m:129)
3   XXX                             0x1003cc4ec ErrorRecovery.crash() + 2672 (ErrorRecovery.swift:286)
4   XXX                             0x1003cb1f4 ErrorRecovery.runNextTask() + 824 (ErrorRecovery.swift:199)
5   XXX                             0x1003cc8c4 closure #1 in closure #1 in ErrorRecovery.tryRelaunchFromCache() + 232 (ErrorRecovery.swift:242)
6   XXX                             0x1003b910c thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed @Sendable () -> () + 28 (<compiler-generated>:0)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x1aa49013c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1530)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x1aa491dd4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:576)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x1aa499400 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 748 (queue.c:3900)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x1aa499f30 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 380 (queue.c:3991)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x1aa4a4cb4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 288 (queue.c:6998)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x1aa4a4528 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 404 (queue.c:6592)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1ff443934 _pthread_wqthread + 288 (pthread.c:2696)
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1ff4400cc start_wqthread + 8 (:-1)

App entry class:
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export const Index = () => {
    useKeepAwake()

    const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
        'regular': require('../assets/fonts/Regular.ttf'),
        'bold': require('../assets/fonts/Bold.ttf'),
        'monospace': require('../assets/fonts/Regular.ttf'),
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        Appearance.setColorScheme("dark")
        const myErrorHandler:ErrorHandlerCallback = (e, isFatal) => {}
        ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler(myErrorHandler)
    },[])

    const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
        if (fontsLoaded) {
            await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
        }
    }, [fontsLoaded]);

    if (!fontsLoaded) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <View onLayout={onLayoutRootView} style={{ backgroundColor: "black", flex: 1, width: "100%" }}>
            <Bootstrap/>
        </View>
    );
}

Thank you,
Niclas
